# access select distinct on certain column

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a table with some search results. The search results maybe repeated because each result may be found using a different metric. I want to then query this table select only the distinct results using the ID column. So to summarize I have a table with an ID column but the IDs may be repeated and I want to select only one of each ID with MS Access SQL, how should I go about doing this?

Ok I have some more info after trying a couple of the suggestions. The Mins, and Maxes won't work because the column they are operating on cannot be shown. I get an error like   `You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression...` I now have all my data sorted, here is what it looks like

```
ID|Description|searchScore
97     test        1  
97     test        .95
120    ball        .94
97     test        .8
120    ball        .7
```

so the problem is that since the rows were put into the table using different search criteria I have duplicated rows with different scores. What I want to do is select only one of each `ID` sorted by the `searchScore` descending. Any ideas?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM tbl_MyTable` doesn't this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM Search_Table;
```

Based on the last update to your question, the following query seems appropriate.

```
SELECT ID, [Description], Max(searchScore)
FROM Search_Table
GROUP BY ID, [Description];
```

However that's nearly the same as Gordon's suggestion from yesterday, so I'm unsure whether this is what you want.

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately that doesn't work as I need to select the search criteria columns too and these are what are differentiating the different IDs. I need the search criteria so that I can sort on it.

Comment: No worries! Thanks for the help! I think I will end up using something along those lines. I am going to have to do some thinking about how I want to sort the results first.

Comment: thank you! That gets me closer. With that query I am getting only one hit on each of the ID's, the problem is they are no longer sorted by `searchScore DESC` any ideas on how I could add that in? Thanks for the help, I'm not very good with SQL

Comment: well I'm not trying to keep important info from you, I promise! I just tried running it with `ORDER BY` and I get the following error: `You tried to excute a query that does not include the specified expression 'ID' as part of an aggregate function. Here is the SQL statement I tried: `SELECT ID, [description] from tblSearchResults ORDER BY Max(searchScore) DESC`

Comment: I meant: `SELECT ID, [Description], Max(searchScore)
FROM Search_Table
GROUP BY ID, [Description] ORDER BY Max(searchScore) DESC;`

Comment: you are my hero! That worked beautifully. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way where you can get one of the search criteria:

```
select id, min(search_criteria)
from t
group by id
```

This will always return the first one alphabetically.  You can also easily get the last one using `max()`.

You could also use:

```
select id, first(search_criteria)
from t
group by id
```

Comment: Thanks! I think that might be the key, but you just opened up a whole new can of worms for me. I just realized that I am going to have to do quite a bit of sorting based on the different criteria before I even think about selecting the distinct entries. But thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: Got my sorting figured out and gave this a try, see my edits above.